# Android NDK Installation with imported project

Tags: android, import, android-ndk, adt

I imported an Android project in eclipse ADT and it needs the Android NDK to work. I downloaded and configured the NDK in `Window > Preferences` and made a few configurations in the project properties from other stackoverflow sources but the project has build errors and is just NOT working....

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project GLTexture ****

\ndk-build all 

Cannot run program "\ndk-build": Launching failed
Error: Program "/ndk-build" is not found in PATH

PATH=[C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program    

Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/ProgramFiles/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Abbas\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\IDEs\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\eclipse;]

**** Build Finished ****
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: You need to add `/ndk-build` to your PATH System variable.

Comment: Please publish your .cproject file

Comment: @hichris123 can u explain the procedure in detail, how exactly do i do that?

Comment: @Anafam What OS are you using?

Comment: @hichris123 windows 7

Comment: Guys do I need to have Cygwin installed for the NDK to work?

Comment: No you don't need cygwin

Comment: I agree, you don't need cygwin.  You may get "cygwin can't be found in path" or similar errors in eclipse. Ignore those.

Comment: That's good I never installed it anyways!

Comment: Do you guys mean the R9b release of the NDK doesn't need Cygwin? I have the R9 one. I'd have to download the R9b otherwise to avoid Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

This error means it can't find the ndk-build command, which is located in the top level folder of the NDK install.  Double check the value you set in Window -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK.  I have mine set to `I:\ADT\android-ndk-r9` and in that folder is the `ndk-build` and `ndk-build.cmd` scripts used by eclipse.  Note that this value is *per workspace*, so if you 've changed workspaces since you've set the ndk path you will need to re-enter it. Also, right click on your project, select properties, and under `C/C++ Build` your `Build command` should be exactly `ndk-build` with optional arguments.

Note that it is NOT required to have the NDK in your system path.  I just confirmed this by removing it from my path (its needed in path if you build from command line), restarting eclipse and rebuilding the project.  But note that you can run `ndk-build` from the command line in your project folder if the NDK is in your path.

Comment: I've already configured the Ndk's location in `windows > preferences` like i mentioned above. I added a new variable named `PATH` in the project's properties...`C/C++ Build > Environment` and in the variable's value i put the location of the Ndk.

Comment: After doing that I was left with just 1 build error on the console. I solved that by going into Windows 7 `system properties > Advanced (tab) > Environment variables` and adding `NDKROOT` as a System Variable to point to the NDK's location on my computer. I also changed the build command in C/C++ Build to `${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd`. I finally got it to work, Thanks for the Reply!